# Delphi: TPicture from TImageList

Tags: delphi, bitmap, image, timagelist

How to get a TPicture from a TImageList?

I need to do `Image1.Picture:=...TPicture` from an image list, to load an image into a TImage.

An image list stores all my PNG images that are transparent.

I tried to use a bitmap (`GetBitmap`), but what I need is transparency. Unfortunatelly, I have a white background using a bitmap.

Thanks!

Comment: A TImageList cannot hold PNGs, only Icons and Bitmaps.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau, so if I use an image list with PNG in a tool bar then that image list automatically makes a transparent background applying a transparent color?

Comment: And do I need to set a transparent color and transparency of a bitmap manually to have an appropriate result in TImage in my case?

Comment: Underlying image list actually holds bitmaps. It is a Windows control.

Comment: @maxfax you can get proper partially transparent images with a plain old TImageList.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, Image List, at its topmost capabilities, can store true-color raster plus 1-bit alpha channel. This corresponds most closely to TIcon storage caps. Feeding PNG to Image List downgrades the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular TImageList uses bitmaps. Although they can be partially transparent, it is actually just a fake. In Delphi you can draw bitmaps to be transparent by assigning them a single transparent color. That exact color will be drawn a 100% transparent, while the other colors are not. Usually the color is taken from the bottom left corner of the image.

TPicture itself doesn't do anything. It is merely a container for TGraphic descendants. You'll have to find a type of image that can be transparent.

A convenient format is PNG. PNG event supports an alpha channel, which means that every pixel can be assigned a different transparency value.

Fortunately there are **TPngImageLists** that combine the ease of TImageList with the power of PNG. You can read [this article](http://www.nldelphi.com/cgi-bin/articles.exe/ShowArticle?ID=16318). It is in Dutch, but maybe Google Translate can help you. Or maybe you can find an english resource on this subject. I've used this imagelist and it's great, because you can have actual icons with an alpha channel and still use them with regular toolbars and speedbuttons.

Comment: TImageList holds partially transparent images quite happily and has done for a long time. I was doing this in D6, although it did need a mild hack to achieve it. The need for the hack was removed quite a few years ago.

Comment: You are overrating "the power of PNG", check my comment to OP's post. Specifically, first paragraph is not true, no fakes at all.

Comment: 1 bit alpha, actually means 'on' or 'off', so a pixel is either fully transparent or fully opaque. Pngs (as well as icons) support an alpha channel which let you make pixels semi transparent. This is particulary helpful for drawing small images on a background that can change. And it can, since everybody has different color settings in Windows, and toolbars can have gradients too. The article I linked to shows this in the image at the top. The left controller icon has an alpha channel, which is especially useful for the pixels at the edge, while the other icon's edge is not so smooth.

Comment: The power of the PNG image list I mentioned, is that it lets you draw these alpha channel images on common controls like toolbuttons and png buttons. That means they will look good, even if your user decided that they want their toolbars to be black or pink. If you got only 1 bit alpha, or just 'transparent pixels or not', you got basically the images that GIF89 supports. And indeed, Delphi allows you to assign a transparent color to bitmaps too. But these images will never look so smooth, unless they happen to have just straight edges and make no use of the alpha channel.